# Skip required check if it's not applicable in github actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a GitHub workflow that applies to only certain events:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - 'foo/**'
  push:
    paths:
      - 'foo/**'
```

I want this workflow check to be required, but when those events do not occur then the build is stalled - it waits for a check that does not start.

How I can make this check required, yet skipped when it's not triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is an official solution for it:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/defining-the-mergeability-of-pull-requests/troubleshooting-required-status-checks#handling-skipped-but-required-checks

I had to create a second workflow as follows:

```yaml
name: ci
on:
  pull_request:
    paths-ignore:
      - 'foo/**'
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: 'echo "No build required" '
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. @pixel Can you tell us what will be the name added to the `required checks` field ? Will you add `ci/build` ?

Comment: name is the same - `build`. You need to have the same name for two jobs and have it required

Comment: I've been testing out various github action features and came across this answer. Works a treat: https://github.com/laurencee/GithubActionTesting/commit/876ef30bc6aff6f981ff829dbee72f3ef2e2714c

And a PR that resulted in the skip required status check executing instead of the build status check: https://github.com/laurencee/GithubActionTesting/pull/10

Comment: What if you have jobs using dynamic matrix and job names can change? Then you would need to build same matrix to skip it? Looks quite hacky. Its also quite clunky in adding required statuses in this case as well, because I have to specify many statuses, even though there is one job defined (with matrix).